# Javascript only allow letters in a input

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there any code to only allow letters in a HTML textbox I have looked everywhere but nothing, I want to only allow LETTERS not 1,2,3,4,5... so on only a,b,c,d,e... you know how it goes, any ideas how to do this?

Obviously allow capital letters to, basically just letters that make words, not numbers, and that it also blocks special characters like $%£^£

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: I'd HIGHLY recommend against doing this . . . it's a terrible user experience to have your input blocked or altered, as you are typing.  Much better to let them type and then validate the value after they are done.

Comment: @LiamHardy where do you see ASP?

Answer (score 1):

html code as bellow

```
 <input type="text" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this);" />
```

and javascript as :

```
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
        try {
            if (window.event) {
                var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e) {
                var charCode = e.which;
            }
            else { return true; }
            if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.Description);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This will only work for English, or languages that share the same ASCII keycodes as English, so be aware of this if you use this in production.